# Iterating over data array in VueJS 2.0

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component, vuejs2

I have a vue component for which I get paginated data from api.

What I want to do is update the iterated list using a smaller pagination total...thus in my vue component template

```
<td v-for="item in listItems">......
</td>
```

and in the script

```
    {
  data (){ return { items:[]; pageSize:5, page:1 } // items is 20 in total; pageSize is 5 per page
  computed :{
    listItems: function(){ 
      var arr = [];
      while (i < this.pageSize) { 
        arr.push(this.items[i + (this.page * this.pageSize)]); 
       i++;
      } 
      return arr ;
      } 
    }, 
    methods:{ 
        getDATA: function(){ this.$http.get().then(response => {
                  this.items = response.data.data; // array of data objects
              }); 
          }
        }
  }
```

but i get an empty array/ i'm guessing I can't just iterate like a normal array

Comment: Your code is incomplete or incorrect.  Where do you actually return anything for listItems?

Comment: Please provide actual code.This thing you posted doesn't tell anything.

Comment: What console says ? I think you are missing this keyword on page, pageSize and items.

Comment: @DavidL I updated the question

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly this might be what you are looking for

```
export default {
  {
    data () { 
      return { 
        items: [],
        page: 1,
        pageSize: 1
      }
    },
    computed: {
      listItems() => { 
        while (i < this.pageSize) { 
          this.items[i + (this.page * this.pageSize)]; 
        }
      } 
    }
  }
}
```

But I'm not sure what you're trying to do so it's the best I can do with limited information, and it looks like you're trying to set data in a computed method, which I'm not 100% sure you can do...

Comment: @Kendall There is vue-paginate component, just let you know https://github.com/TahaSh/vue-paginate :)

Comment: @Belmin tried that but was not able to implement it properly. I am using table rows...and his uses list items